# Is the join necessary for the Group By clause?

Tags: sql

Given this schema:

```
Hotel(hotelNo, hotelName, city)                      #hotelNo is PK
Room (roomNo, hotelNo, type, price)                  #(roomNo, hotelNo) is PK
Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) #(hotelNo,guestNo, dateFrom) is PK
Guest(guestNo, GuestName, GuestAddress)              #guestNo is PK
```

**Q:** **What is the lost income from unoccupied rooms at each hotel today?**

Looking at the solution I ended up with a very different answer (more complicated but basically I found `all rooms in hotels` and computed the `Difference` set operator against `all rooms which are booked today` and then calculated the price for the remaining rooms with a group by clause - I'm not even sure it would work, but on paper it looks valid). However, looking at the example solution:

```
SELECT hotelNo, SUM(price) FROM Room r
WHERE roomNo NOT IN
    (SELECT roomNo FROM Booking b, Hotel h
    WHERE (dateFrom <= CURRENT_DATE AND
        dateTo >= CURRENT_DATE) AND
        b.hotelNo = h.hotelNo)
GROUP BY hotelNo;
```

Why do we need to join the Booking and Hotel. I see we join the two relations based on `b.hotelNo=h.hotelNo` but looking at the schema, the Booking provides details on the RoomNo (which is booked) and provides information on which Hotel and the dates... Surely that's all the information we need to work with a Group By clause and achieve our desired result? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: First never use implicit joins; they are a SQL anti pattern.

Comment: Your query makes no sense if multiple hotels can have the same room numbers which, from my experience, they do.In fact your table structure doesn't make sense unless you are using RoomNo and HotelNo as a compound  PK in the Room table.

Comment: @HLGEM thanks for the tip. I will bare that in mind (although this is directly from the answer sheet). I've also added the the keys in my schema and yes, the Room is a compound key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `hotel` table.  The foreign key value in `booking` is fine for the comparisons, assuming that all the bookings are, indeed, for a hotel.

This should work fine, even if both `HotelNo` and `RoomNo` are needed to identify a booking and room:

```
SELECT hotelNo, SUM(price)
FROM Room r
WHERE r.roomNo NOT IN (SELECT b.roomNo
                       FROM Booking b
                       WHERE (dateFrom <= CURRENT_DATE AND dateTo >= CURRENT_DATE) AND
                             b.hotelNo = r.hotelNo
                      )
GROUP BY hotelNo;
```

However, it is awkward to split a paired relationship like this.  Use `not exists` instead:

```
SELECT hotelNo, SUM(price)
FROM Room r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Booking b
                  WHERE (dateFrom <= CURRENT_DATE AND dateTo >= CURRENT_DATE) AND
                        b.hotelNo = r.hotelNo and
                        b.roomNo = r.roomNo
                 )
GROUP BY hotelNo;
```

Of course, you can write this as a `join`, but even with a `join`, the `hotel` table is not needed:

```
SELECT r.hotelNo, SUM(r.price)
FROM Room r left join 
     Booking b 
     ON b.dateFrom <= CURRENT_DATE AND
        b.dateTo >= CURRENT_DATE and
        b.roomNo = r.roomNo and b.hotelNo = r.hotelNo
WHERE b.roomNo is null       
GROUP BY r.hotelNo;
```

Comment: Gordon thanks for the fantastic answer/'s (not the first time you've helped me tonight!, Out of curiosity, which out of the three would be considered the 'better' solution? Is there any significant performance difference?

Comment: @gudthing . . . In this case, the second or third are "better".  In SQL, `NOT IN` behaves unexpectedly when the subquery returns `NULL`s.  Although you learn `NOT IN` first and it makes more sense when reading, it can be dangerous.  For that reason, I advocate using `NOT EXISTS` or the explicit `join`.  By the way, you seem to have a pretty good grasp of SQL and databases; you need a more advanced course.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is more the type of query I would write:

```
SELECT hotelNo, SUM(price) FROM Room r
left join 
    (SELECT roomNo , hotelNo
    FROM Booking b 
    join Hotel h ON  b.hotelNo = h.hotelNo
    WHERE dateFrom <= CURRENT_DATE AND
        dateTo >= CURRENT_DATE)  a
        ON a. roomNo = r.roomNo and a.hotelNo= r.hotelNo
 WHERE a.roomNo is null       
GROUP BY hotelNo;
```

Comment: if the Booking relation already has the `hotelNo`, why do we need to join the Booking relation with Hotel? What would happen if we left out the join with `Hotel` and just did `r.hotelNo=b.hotelNo`

Comment: Because you want the rooms not booked for each hotel. Hotel a might have rooms 1, 2,3 booked and hotel B might have rooms 2, 4, 6, booked.  SO you want teh sum of teh rental for hotel a of rooms 4,5,6,7 and of rooms 1, 3, 7 for Hotel b.  Both Hotel and room number are required to get the right result.